How do I retrieve domain user information from controller using WMI
I am working on a web controller to display and (ultimately) modify domain information for users. Ideally I want userName, full name, status (locked?) and whether they are logged in.
I have gotten this far
 # Define the target domain controller
 $domainController = "myController"
 # Hardcoded credentials (for demonstration purposes only, not recommended in production)
 $username = "myUser@my.domain"
 $password = ConvertTo-SecureString "MyP@ssw03d!*" -AsPlainText -Force
 $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)

 # Connect to the specified domain controller remotely using hardcoded credentials
 $sessionQuery = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogonSession -ComputerName $domainController -Credential $credential

 $sessionQuery | ForEach-Object {
     Write-Host $_.Properties | ForEach-Object {
        $propertyData=[System.Management.PropertyData]$_
        Write-Host $($propertyData.Name)  $($propertyData.Value)
        Write-Host "----------------------"
    
     }
 }

But the only data it returns from Powershell is System.Management.PropertyData repeated over and over. Not even the divider is being printed.
I am completely unfamiliar with PowerShell scripting but I haven't been able to find a way to managed this through C#. I am looking for either a solution to this script OR a reference on retrieving what I need from within C#.
Thank you.

Might as well replace GetWimObject with Get-CimInstance. The WIM commands are not available in PowerShell 6+.

Write-Host $_.Properties doesn't output anything, it only renders text on the screen buffer, so the inner loop is no different from $null |ForEach-Object { ... }

After more research I moved from WMI to using DirectorySearcher in C#:
 var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
 var config = builder.Build();
 var admin = config.GetSection("Admin");

 // Set up the Directory Entry
 DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://mcad2.local", admin.GetValue("userName", ""), admin.GetValue("password", ""));

 // Set up the Directory Searcher
 DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
 searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))"; // Filter to retrieve only user objects

 // Perform the Search
 SearchResultCollection r = searcher.FindAll();

This gave me the details I was looking for within the active directory, and can easily be converted to JSON for transport to the web.

Write-Host is the wrong cmdlet for the job - it prints output directly to the screen, and doesn't produce any standard output that a downstream cmdlet can consume. Drop it completely:
$dcCimSession = New-CimSession -ComputerName $domainController -Credential $credential
$sessionQuery = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogonSession -CimSession $dcCimSession

$sessionQuery | ForEach-Object {
    # when using the CIM cmdlets, the meta-property you want is `CimInstanceProperties` - 
    $_.CimInstanceProperties | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "$($_.Name)  $($_.Value)"
        Write-Host '----------------------'    
    }
}

